# How do you find the iterator in the middle of two iterators?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to convert my implementation of quicksort into a template that can be used with other containers besides a vector.

Originally I used indexes to find the middle index, e.g. `(first + last) / 2`. How can I find the middle of two iterators?

Comment: BTW, why implement your own quicksort? std::sort should cover quicksorting, and there's also stable_sort, partial_sort_copy, etc.

Comment: I'm doing Project Euler and wanted to look into some sorting algorithms, although if I plan to reuse it in the future, you're right--I might as well just use std::sort.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`std::distance`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/distance/) can measure the distance between two iterators as efficiently as possible.

[`std::advance`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/advance/) can increment an iterator as efficiently as possible.

I still wouldn't want to quicksort a linked list, though :)

Comment: Why not quicksort a linked list?  Finding the middle is unnecessary for quicksort...

Comment: @DietrichEpp: True, but there's a reason that `std::sort` specifically requires random-access iterators.

Comment: I'm sure there's a technical reason, but it has nothing to do with the algorithm.  It is easy to quicksort a linked list.

Comment: It is just inefficient to walk up and down the lists constantly. You spend most of your time accessing "node->next" and "node->prev" and barely any time actually performing a sort. Performance-wise you are likely going to do much better by copying your data into a vector and sorting it there.

Answer (score 5):

use:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/distance/

and

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/advance/

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
bool isMovingFirst = true;
while(first != last) {
  if(isMovingFirst) {
    ++first;
  } else {
    --last;
  }
  isMovingFirst = !isMovingFirst;
}
```

Comment: It's generally considered bad form to reimplement things that are in the standard libraries. Don't Repeat Yourself and all.

Comment: Oh, I agree with that completely. I only wrote it because it operates in the same amount of steps as distance (without calling advance). *But* then distance+advance is still low cost relative to the O(n log n) time complexity of quicksort, so I definitely see your point as valid in this case.

Comment: Well, if we're going for efficiency, you've got a whole extra bool going on that you don't need... try this instead:

for (;;) {
    if (first == last) break;  ++first; 
    if (first == last) break;  --last;  
}

Answer (score 0):

To find middle iterator you should use:

```
first + (last - first) / 2
```

Comment: This is not correct. Your solution requires random access iterators. OP asked for a solution which would be container independent.